# How can i check the state of spell checker option on an android phone?

Tags: android

I've searched for check the state of spell checker option on an android phone.

I have this code in my `OnClickListener` method and i would like to check the state after it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName theComponent = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$SpellCheckersSettingsActivity" );
intent.setComponent( theComponent );
startActivity(intent);
```

In this method I requested that the user to enable the spell checker but when it comes back on the app I want to check if he really did it. For the moment I can't get information of the state of the componentName. I just want the state of the spell checker to see if it is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Could you check / set InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Comment: Ok i understand, you want that i get information about the spell checker across the inputtype that's right ?but i don't see how can i do that, i don't know the methods to use.